# Getting error in python

Tags: python

Getting the following error in my code. How to fix it up

```
    list_of_words = []
    pg_num = each_page.find('PageNumber').text
    zones = each_page.findall('Zone')
    for zone in zones:
        Zone_Number = zone.find('ZoneNumber').text
        lines = zone.findall('Line')
        for line in lines:
            LineNumber = line.find('LineNumber').text
            Line_Text = eol(line.find('OCRCharacters').text, zone_no=Zone_Number, line_number=LineNumber,
                            page_no=pg_num)
            list_of_words.append(Line_Text)
    join_all_vals = ''.join(list_of_words)
    replace_space = join_all_vals.replace(" ", "")
    get_each_alpha_count = Counter(replace_space)
    list_of_vals=[]
    print(type(get_each_alpha_count),get_each_alpha_count[0])
    for ke,va in get_each_alpha_count:
        new_format_val=ke + "|" + va
        list_of_vals.append(new_format_val)
    print(list_of_vals)
    exit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 93, in <module>
    CT.pagenumber()
  File "C:\Users\karthik\uat\pyinstaller_testing_reference\three_pyinstaller_test\source\PageTraits\main.py", line 46, in pagenumber
    for ke,va in get_each_alpha_count:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `items()` when iterating the `Counter` which is a `dict` like object:

```
# ...
for ke, va in get_each_alpha_count.items():
    # ...
```

Otherwise, you are just iterating the keys and the assingment to two variables will fail unless the keys are tuples (of length 2) themselves. You also might wanna consider a better string building strategy since you cannot just concatenate `int` and `str`:

```
new_format_val = "|".join(map(str, (ke, va)))
# OR
new_format_val = "{}|{}".format(ke, va)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 93, in <module>
    CT.pagenumber()
  File "C:\Users\karthik\uat\pyinstaller_testing_reference\three_pyinstaller_test\source\PageTraits\main.py", line 47, in pagenumber
    new_format_val=ke + "|" + va
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Or `new_format_val = f"{ke}|{va}" ` in python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: @FHTMitchell True, even though I haven't really befriended that option yet :) mostly for the lack of 3.6 projects.

Comment: still getting the same error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @schwobaseggl  actually im looping the list  values right?